# how to use bind function to "<li>", which was kept dynamically?

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

`<li>` is kept by the **set_input()** function, After getting **data** by using a **getJSON()**.
But even bind function is not working.
could anybody pls help me!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$.getJSON("sample1.php?",
    function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i,j){
                testA[j.id]=j.name;
            });
            set_input("div_1","continent",testA);
    });

$("#"+div_D+" ul li").bind("click",function(){
    $("#"+div_D+" input[type='text']").val($(this).text());
})  
});


  function set_input(div_D,name_N,Array_A){

    $("#"+div_D).html("<input id="+name_N+">");
    var str="<ul>";
    $.each(Array_A,function(m,n){
        str +="<li>"+n+"</li>"
    })
    $("#"+div_D+" input[type="text"]").after(str);
  }


  This is JSON array:
[ {'id':'0','name':'Africa'},{'id':'1','name':'Americas'},{'id':'2','name':'Asia'},{'id':'3','name':'Europe'},{'id':'4','name':'Oceania'} ]
```

Comment: 'set-input' could be your problem, or just a typo, '-' isn't valid in javascript function names

Comment: even i removed that one it's not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to bind to an item which does not exist in the DOM yet.

Move

```
$("#"+div_+" ul li").bind("click",function(){
        $("#"+div_+" input[type="text"]").val($(this).text());
})
```

to the last line of the set-input function. i.e.  to

```
function set-input(div_,name_,Array_){
        $("#"+div_).html("<input id="+name_+">");
        var str="<ul>";
        $.each(Array_,function(m,n){
                str +="<li>"+n+"</li>"
        })
        $("#"+div_+" input[type="text"]").after(str);

    $("#"+div_+" ul li").bind("click",function(){
        $("#"+div_+" input[type="text"]").val($(this).text());
    })
}
```

*P.S. You have quite a few typos.*

Comment: Is there any other possible way?
I don't want to keep that code to the last line of the set-input function

Comment: Because that set-input function is in another file, I want to write click function in another file!

Comment: Add ur code in a custom event that attaches to set-input() and then trigger that event :-)

Comment: Additionally you could use $().live()

Answer (score 0):

I see several errors:

- testA is never declared, and will be assumed global
- set-input isn't a valid function name
- `" input[type="text"]"` should be `" input[type='text']"`
- str should be equal to `$("ul")` (maybe, not entirely sure what you're trying for)
- you are creating multiple inputs which will all have the same id, use class instead

It would help if you posted the HTML you are running this against

Also as a rule of thumb for writing clean jQuery code, I try to almost never use concatenation inside a $(), there is almost always a better way.